# on(“click”) only firing after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an anchor link to load more posts the issue is it's not firing in the first click (at first time ONLY) but to load more posts in the second time, it works with first click.

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#load-more').on('click', function (){
      
        if( !(count > total) && (count > 1) ){
            //Function
            loadArticle(count, total, load_method, page_id, blog_style, blog_page_image_size, show_post_animation, item_animation);
        }
      
        count++;

        // Function
        noMoreArticles(count, total, load_method);

        
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="load-more" href="#">Load More</a>
```

Comment: If you want to use a doubleclick feature, you can use the ´dblclick()´ function from jQuery. (Reference: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(window).load(function() {`  try with `jQuery(document).readyfunction() {`

may be some images are not loading so that is the issue